# How to add the count values of similar event id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

I have a table in which there are three columns i.e. Event id, Event and Counts. There can be multiple rows with same event id having their own counts values under Counts column. I have to find out the distinct Event id and then add up their corresponding count values and display the output table with distinct Event id, Event and Count in which the count value will be total sum of available counts. I tried to show tabular form of what I want to do as following:

```
+--------+--------------+----------+
|           Ashley Janes           |   
+--------+--------------+----------+
|Eventid | Event        | Count    |   
+--------+--------------+----------+
|  5     | Wash apple   |    10    |
|  2     | cook potatoes|    20    |
|  8     | cut chillies |     5    | 
+--------+--------------+----------+
|         Taylor Perry             |   
+--------+---------------+---------+
|  2     | cook potatoes |  30     |    
|  5     | Wash apple    |  40     |
|  8     | cut chillies  |  60     |

Now I have to add count values of corresponding event id and display it in a result table as following::

+--------+--------------+----------+
|Eventid | Event        | Count    |   
+--------+--------------+----------+
|  5     | Wash apple   |    50    |
|  2     | cook potatoes|    50    |
|  8     | cut chillies |    65    | 
+--------+--------------+----------+
```

so far I have done following:

```
Response.Write "<div><table><tr>"
Response.Write"<td class='tdcell1'>Event ID</td><td class='tdcell1'>Count</td></tr>"
Response.Write"<tr><td align=center width= '15%'></td><td><div class= 'resultSum'></div></td></tr>"
Response.Write"</table><div>"

<script>
$(function() {
        GetEventIds('#displaytable')
    });
function GetEventIds(tableIdWithHash) {
    var eventIds = [];
    var eventSum = Number(0);
        var count = Number(0);

    $(tableIdWithHash).find('.Idevent').each(function(i){
    var eId = $(this).html();
    if (eventIds.indexOf(eId) === -1)
        eventIds.push($(this).html());

        if (eId = eventIds)
            count++;
                eventSum += Number($(this).html());
            $(".resultSum").html(eventSum);
    });
    alert('EventIds: ' + JSON.stringify(eventIds)); 
    return eventIds;
}           
</script>
    Code for the table need to be parsed.
<table id= 'displaytable' width='35%' border=1 style= 'margin-bottom:35px; margin-top:35px;'>
    <tr>
        <td class='tdcell1'>Event ID</td>
        <td class='tdcell1'>Event</td>
        <td class='tdcell1'>Count</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='font-size:13px;'>
        <td align='right' class='tdcell1' colspan='3'>Ashley Janes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='font-size:13px;'>
        <td align=center class='Idevent' width= '15%'> 5 </td>
        <td align=center class='eventNames' width= '35%'> Wash Apple </td>
        <td class='eventCounts' align=center width= '15%'>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='font-size:13px;'>
        <td align=center class='Idevent' width= '15%'> 2 </td>
        <td align=center class='eventNames' width= '35%'> Cook Potatoes </td>
        <td class='eventCounts' align=center width= '15%'>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='font-size:13px;'>
        <td align='right' class='tdcell1' colspan='3'>Taylor Perry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='font-size:13px;'>
        <td align=center class='Idevent' width= '15%'> 2 </td>
        <td align=center class='eventNames' width= '35%'> Cook Potatoes </td>
        <td class='eventCounts' align=center width= '15%'>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='font-size:13px;'>
        <td align=center class='Idevent' width= '15%'> 5 </td>
        <td align=center class='eventNames' width= '35%'> Wash Apple </td>
        <td  class='eventCounts' align=center width= '15%'>106</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My code gives me the output for the sum of the event id not the counts. How do I do it using JavaScript? Please help.

Comment: 1st. please post an example of the table-markup you have to parse. 2nd. what does the `#resultSum`-node contain (logically) and are you sure there is only one node with this ID in the whole document?

Comment: @Thomas: Actually the table that I need to parse is the result of some another table. I thought it might be complicated if I keep it. So I just gave a simple example of a table as shown above. Secondly, #resultSum is just a div I created inside a table cell td, it doesn't have anything but the result of the addition of counts will eventually goes there and yes there is no other ID with #resultSum.

Comment: I have added the table-markup that needed to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code and wether works as you expect it.

```
$(function() {
    GetEventIds('#displaytable')
});

//this is a bad function, because it does way more than it says.
function GetEventIds(tableIdWithHash) {

    //a little helper
    //convert a value to int32. any non-numeric value -> 0
    //only the low 32-bits are kept, if the value exceeds the range
    //and removes all bits after the dot (2.9 -> 2 and -2.9 -> -2)
    function int(v){ return v|0; }

    var eventSum = 0;
    var events = {};

    $(tableIdWithHash).find('.Idevent').each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this);

        var eId = $this.text().trim();

        //finding the .eventCount-node of this row
        var count = int( $this.siblings('.eventCounts').text().trim() );

        events[eId] = int( events[eId] ) + count;

        //still don't get what #resultSum should contain (logically)
        //the total amount of events, independent of the event-id?
        eventSum += count;
    });
    $("#resultSum").html(eventSum);

    var eventIds = Object.keys(events);
    console.log('EventIds: ', eventIds);
    console.log('Event counts by Id: ', JSON.stringify(events));

    return eventIds;
}
```

Still need some info on the purpose/meaning of `#resultSum`. I made just an assumption on that; am i right?

And as I commented on the function, What is the purpose of this function? It does more than it says. This may lead to confusion/bugs. Maybe you want to split this into multiple functions, or rename it and drop the return-value.

Or maybe you want to parse the table into some data-structure and operate on this? But then again it may be wiser to paste JSON out of the backend, than parsing some markup.